# Subtracting two years and round up if more than half a year

Tags: ruby, date, rounding, subtraction

I have the following:

```
y1 = Date.parse("2008-02-01")
y2 = Date.today
```

I then want to

1. subtract `y2 - y1`
2. convert the result to some kind of number class
3. divide the result by 365.25 and round the result up if it exceeds .5

**My main question is point 2, what number class I should use? And that will probably answer point 3 I guess.**

Or perhaps there is an even more efficient way of subtracting two dates and receive number of years, rounded up/down to the closest whole number?

Comment: Searching SO on 'Ruby date difference' brings up quite a few hits that look relevant to your question.  Have you had a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of subtraction is already a number (days as rational numbers).

```
((y2 - y1) / 365.25).round
# => 6
```

Answer (score -1):

use can use

```
result = ((y2 - y1) / 365.25).round
```

this will give you the difference of number of days in integer. now you can check through ternary operator whether it is greater than .5 or not